# W/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzal@b962d36

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I am trying to implement Phone Authentication using Firebase while signing in using a valid phone number I get the following log message.

```
2018-12-24 22:03:10.880 3021-3021/packagename W/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzal@b962d36
2018-12-24 22:03:12.391 3021-3021/packagename D/LoginActivity: com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@bcdfd40
```

These are my dependencies

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.1.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:2.0.1'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.1@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
// Check for v11.4.2 or higher
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.8'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

build.gradle (Project level)

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
    }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.26.1'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
    }
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And I have added the recently downloaded **google-services.json** file into this project. Actually, this code was running perfectly before I don't know why now it's showing this error after I made a few UI changes & increased the project version number.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem today with an old device Moto E 2nd Generation. I figured out that I had to update Play Services before I make use of any Firebase services (Auth included).

Hope it works for you!